# How to convert "traditional TeX" to Unicode?

Tags: luatex, unicode

For example if we have `$\mathcal{A}$` in the code, add some conversion lines and TeX it using LuaTeX I hope to see the symbol `\0x1D49C` in Unicode instead of '\0x41' of the font `cmsy10`. Is this possible?

Comment: It may not be what you're after, but this website might be of some use: https://www.johndcook.com/unicode_latex.html

Comment: Did you try `\usepackage{unicode-math}`?

Comment: if you use unicode-math then`\mathcal` will do what you want.